# "Why is there the definite article in “The increase of GDP…”

Tags: articles, usage, definite-article

> **The** increase of GDP factor helped the country to combat paucity.

Why "the" is used before "increase" when already there is a particular factor that is GDP? If it hadn't be given, only, then, "the" could have been written before "increase" ?

Comment: What's the source of the quote? It's ungrammatical anyway, whatever 'XYP factor' is supposed to be.

Comment: It is not a quote. I have formulated a sentence to ask that question

Comment: It's certainly an odd sentence and not very natural. The rest of your question isn't very clear either. If you're talking about a specific increase (particularly one you've referred to before), you would indeed use "the increase", but if you meant something else you could also use "an increase" or "any increase" which would change the meaning but also be grammatical.

Comment: @StuartF "GDP factor" is a term belongs to economics.It is a measure of a country's economic performance.

Comment: The adjective *paucity* is used incorrectly here, it should be **poverty**. We talk about **a paucity of choice** or **there is a paucity of new ideas** to express a very limited range or number. Poverty is the noun form of *poor*.

Answer (score 2):

(the inclusion of the word "factor" was a mistake, I shall assume that "The increase of GDP helped..." was intended, and "poverty" replaces "paucity".)

This is just one sentence, and missing context.  The use of "The" indicates that the author is referring to a definite instance of increasing GDP, and that "which increase" can be understood from the context.

For example this sentence could have been part of a paragraph talking about "economic development in the 1980s" If so, then the answer to the question "which increase of GDP" would be understood to be "the increase that occurred in the 1980s"

On its own, the sentence is unclear.  A definite increase in GDP is referred to, but there is no context to enable the reader to know which one the author is writing about, except that it must be the increase that occurred during, or just before, the effort to combat poverty.